# Matlab ARGV from Commandline

Tags: matlab, octave

i want to run a Matlab from commandline with arguments.
Like `matlab -r test.m ARGV1 ARGV2 ARGV3`

is there any possebility to do it like this ?

Greetz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you invoke

```
$ matlab -r "test ARGV1 ARGV2 ARGV3"
```

That is equivalent to

```
>>test('ARGV1', 'ARGV2', 'ARGV3')
```

inside MATLAB.

Comment: so i could start my matlab application from the batch with matlab -nojvm -r "programm.m /tmp/output.dat" like this ?

Comment: Yes. You could also do matlab -nojvm -r "myprogram('/tmp/output.dat')". Consider adding -nosplash as well, to suppress the MATLAB splash screen.